# Prove that graph has at least one cycle of length at least $\delta+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have to answer the question : "Is it true that in all finite graphs (connected graphs) wchich $\delta \ge 2$ ($\delta$ is the smallest degree of vertices in a graph) exists the cycle of length equal to $\delta+1$ or longer". I believe this statement is true. I drew some graphs and it seems to be true. I do not know how to prove this in mathematical way. I will glad for help and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $P=(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ be a path of maximum length in your graph. Consider the neighbours of $v_1$.