# Prove that if $\delta(V)\geq 2$, the graph $G=(V,E)$ has a cycle of length $\delta(V)+1$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $\delta(G)=\min_{v\in V}d(v)$ where $d(v)$ is the degree of $v$.

> Prove that if $\delta(G)\geq 2$, the graph $G=(V,E)$ has a cycle of length $\delta(V)+1$.

It look to have a problem... take for example $C_5$, we have that $\delta(G)=2$ for all $v\in V$, but there is no cycle of length $3$.

Comment: Is it not length (at least) $\delta(V)+1$?

Comment: Yes it is, otherwise consider a pentagon. The miminal degree is two but it has no triangles.

Comment: It is certainly true if you say "at least" instead of "equal to."

Comment: For a hint on the proof, check out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657118/prove-that-graph-has-at-least-one-cycle-of-length-at-least-delta1?rq=1

Comment: ok great, therefore there is a mistakes in my exercice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a maximal path $v_1,v_2\dots v_n$, since the path is maximal all of the neighbours of $v_1$ are in the graph since othwerwise the path could be elongated. Because of this  $v_1$ has at least $\delta(V)$ neighbours in the graph. The one that is farthest away will be $v_k$ with $k\geq1+\delta(V)$.

Therefore taking $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots v_{k-1},v_k,v_1$ gives us the desired cycle of length **at least** $\delta(V)+1$